# What does "The following query failed" ";"" mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

While trying to update a trigger, MySQL tells me the query ";" failed. How is ";" even a query in MySQL's view is beyond me.

The exact message is:

> The following query has failed: ";" MySQL said: #1065 - Query was empty

Here's the new trigger (AFTER INSERT):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE vIdPlacet VARCHAR(40);
DECLARE vTypeTravaux VARCHAR(32);
DECLARE vEssence VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT '-';
DECLARE vClasseHau VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT '-';
DECLARE vNoMesurag int;

DECLARE new_id_parcelle INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE new_no_microplacette INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

IF NEW.deleted = 0 THEN
    SELECT id_parcelle, no_microplacette
    INTO new_id_parcelle, new_no_microplacette
    FROM microplacette
    WHERE id_microplacette = NEW.id_microplacette;

    SELECT travaux, no_mesurag, id__placet
    INTO vTypeTravaux, vNoMesurag, vIdPlacet
    FROM secteur
    LEFT JOIN parcelle ON secteur.id_secteur = parcelle.id_secteur
    WHERE id_parcelle = new_id_parcelle; 

    IF vTypeTravaux = 'inventaire' THEN
        SELECT abbreviation INTO vEssence FROM essences WHERE _id = NEW.id_essence;


        IF NEW.hauteur_15 = 1 THEN
            SET vClasseHau = '15CM+';
        END IF;

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM imported_pres_ess WHERE id__placet = vIdPlacet AND
                                                             caracteris = '-' AND
                                                             classe_hau = vClasseHau AND
                                                             essence = vEssence AND
                                                             no_mesurag = vNoMesurag AND
                                                             no_micro_p = new_no_microplacette) = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO imported_pres_ess (id__placet, caracteris, classe_hau, essence, no_mesurag, no_micro_p)
                   VALUES (vIdPlacet, '-', vClasseHau, vEssence, vNoMesurag, new_no_microplacette);
        END IF; 


        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM imported_semi_gau WHERE id__placet = vIdPlacet AND
                                                             classe_hau = vClasseHau AND
                                                             essence = vEssence AND
                                                             no_mesurag = vNoMesurag AND
                                                             no_micro_p = new_no_microplacette) = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO imported_semi_gau (id__placet, classe_hau, essence, no_mesurag, no_micro_p)
                   VALUES (vIdPlacet, vClasseHau, vEssence, vNoMesurag, new_no_microplacette);
        END IF; 


        IF NEW.diametre > 0 THEN
            SET vClasseHau = 'D2_D8';
        ELSE
            SET vClasseHau = '-';
        END IF;

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM imported_pres_ess WHERE id__placet = vIdPlacet AND
                                                             caracteris = '-' AND
                                                             classe_hau = vClasseHau AND
                                                             essence = vEssence AND
                                                             no_mesurag = vNoMesurag AND
                                                             no_micro_p = new_no_microplacette) = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO imported_pres_ess (id__placet, caracteris, classe_hau, essence, no_mesurag, no_micro_p)
                   VALUES (vIdPlacet, '-', vClasseHau, vEssence, vNoMesurag, new_no_microplacette);
        END IF; 


        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM imported_semi_gau WHERE id__placet = vIdPlacet AND
                                                             classe_hau = vClasseHau AND
                                                             essence = vEssence AND
                                                             no_mesurag = vNoMesurag AND
                                                             no_micro_p = new_no_microplacette) = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO imported_semi_gau (id__placet, classe_hau, essence, no_mesurag, no_micro_p)
                   VALUES (vIdPlacet, vClasseHau, vEssence, vNoMesurag, new_no_microplacette);
        END IF; 
    END IF;
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the trigger I was updating got deleted in the meantime, so I was updating a trigger that didn't exist anymore.

I found out after refreshing the page (the trigger was gone from the trigger list).

I simply recreated the trigger anew and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating the procedure you show, but I don't get any error.

The error about "empty statement" happens when you try to execute a query through the API but the query string is empty.

I can duplicate the error in the mysql client this way:

```
mysql> set @s = '';

mysql> prepare stmt from @s;
ERROR 1065 (42000): Query was empty
```

So I suggest you look not at the stored procedure, but whatever code you're executing this from, and check that every time you try to execute a query, that you submit a non-empty string.